# Delete all records from all the tables MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-delete

Im trying to delete all the records from all the tables with the below code. It may sound funny but used to work a week ago. When I needed to re-run the code  it did not run. when I click run button Macros small window is popping up and asking to provide a macro name. But list of names is empty.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function del()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
       If tdf.Name Like "PB*" Then
           db.Execute "DELETE FROM [" & tdf.Name & "]"
           
       End If
   Next
   
End Function
```

Comment: Functions do not show up in "Run macro" box.

Comment: how should I fix it?

Comment: Use a Sub instead.

Comment: well, not there is not result, it does not delete. I have assigned this code to a button. and when I click it give me this `the expression you entered has a function name that microsoft access can't find` but its Public sub now instead of function

Comment: I do not know how you call the code. In your post you are saying you click the run button and I assumed it is the run button in the VBE. Please edit your post accrodingly and describe excactly what are you doing and what fails.

Comment: to run the sub either highlight it and hit run in the menu or bring up the immediate window (usually control G) and type the sub name and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details, your fundamental issue is context. By syntax alone, your code should be runnable. (Although, ideally it should have proper error handling and release `DAO` objects). But your `Function` code depends on *how* it is called and *where* it is resides in an Access project.

In MS Access, `Public` code in a standard, named module (i.e., *not* behind any form or report) should be viewable by any object even inside SQL queries and table properties.

However, to run  a function behind a form control, you can place your code behind the form module (or aforementioned standard module) and do any of the equivalent actions to run it using Propery Sheet of form design:

- **Expression Builder**: Expand the `On Click` button event with [expression builder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-expression-builder-56214db9-8b54-44f3-bc19-2a55427b5d4c) and enter `=myfunction()`. Pass any needed parameters. Equals symbol and open parentheses for empty parameters are required. This does not work for subroutines.
- **Macro Builder**: Expand the `On Click` button event with macro builder and use [`RunCode`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/runcode-macro-action-e6a62d3f-02c6-4daf-a5f7-402fd600bed4) action. As docs advise, do not use the equals, `=`, symbol. This does not work for subroutines.
- **Module Builder**: Expand the `On Click` button event with module builder and inside the auto-created subroutine denoted with `Sub ... End Sub`, enter the line `Call myfunction()` or on its own line without parentheses: `myfunction`. Unlike previous two above, this can also work for subroutines. Be sure to add error handling here.

With that said, if you want to run function as a one-off process in VBE, place your function in standard module. Then from Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) at bottom, type `Call myfunction()` or `myfunction`. If code is a subroutine, place cursor anywhere in the `Sub` and from menu bar, simply click the green right arrow to run.